# Unknown column 'add_new_page' in 'where clause'

Tags: wordpress

After installing the wordpress plugin **Learnpress** on my wordpress theme i got an error like 
**WordPress database error: [Unknown column 'add_new_page' in 'where clause'] 
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE 1 AND ID IN(add_new_page,124,112,add_new_page) AND post_status <> 'trash'**
Can anybody help me throuth this issue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means, you don't have 'add_new_page' column in wp_posts table.

did you check this?

This is complete query:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE 1 AND ID IN(add_new_page,124,112,add_new_page) AND post_status
```

This is example syntax:

```
 SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE id IN (5,4,3,1,6) and post_status = 1;
```